# SQL how to update a column with a value that depends on the value of a different column in the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with 2 date columns, open_date and close_date. And when I insert a new row the close_date can be null. But in the future I will want to update the close_date, and I want to ensure that the close_date is bigger than the open_date?
Thanx

I'm using oracle...

Answer (score 1):

A [check constraint](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187550.aspx) like this will do ask you ask:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD CONSTRAINT CK_open_date_before_close_date
   CHECK (open_date < close_date);
```

This will reject any transactions that update the table to a state that violates the condition. If, for example, you updated 5 rows but only one of them violated the constraint, the entire update will fail.

Additionally, I would recommend that instead of `NULL` for an open-ended close date, you use a sentinel value of `99991231`. There are many reasons for this, not the least of which is performance of queries (so you can do simple inequality statements without needing an `OR IS NULL` clause). You can additionally then make the column `NOT NULL` and simplify the above check condition. This also affects front-end application code positively.

**UPDATE**

The check constraint does not require `OR close_date IS NULL` in it, since if `close_date` is `NULL`, the whole expression will be evaluated to `NULL`, and this will not violate the `CHECK` constraint.

Comment: Im using oracle, and an error poped up with the messege: Columns check constraint cannot reference to other columns

Comment: What version of Oracle? It works fine in Oracle 11g.

Comment: Yes, it works. but when I try to insert rows (using a Data generator - PL/SQL) it adds rows that do not match that constraint.

Comment: You don't need the `OR close_date IS NULL` part. If a `CHECK` constraint results to `UNKNOWN`, the row is allowed.

Comment: There are some problems with sentinel values though. If I do `AVG(close_date)` for example, I'll have a skewed result.

Comment: Thanks for the comment on `OR IS NULL` @ypercube! Averaging dates is interesting. Without having spent a long time thinking about it, I still would advocate sentinel values because you have to make *some* decision about how to handle those `NULL`s--that they are excluded by default in an aggregate is still a decision to exclude them, and making this decision explicit via `WHERE close_date != '99991231'` seems reasonable to me. The other benefits of performance just seem more important. I'd also offer that the `NULL` way breaks `Max()`, for which `9991231` could be the desired answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a check constraint to make sure Close_date is bigger than the Open_Date,

```
ALTER TABLE Table_Name
ADD CONSTRAINT ck_Con_Name CHECK (Close_date  > Open_Date)
```

To make sure a value is provided for Close_Date column and its not left null, make the column NON-NULABLE.

For this you will need to make sure first there isnt any NULL Values in that column. UPDATE the column to some defualt value. Then Alter table definition something like this...

```
ALTER TABLE Table_Name
ALTER COLUMN Close_date  DATETIME NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score -1):

You may be needing the `CHECK` Constraints.

PLease refer to the [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp)

Comment: I tried, it tells me that Columns check constraint cannot reference to other columns. any ideas?

Comment: please take a look at [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eb632) and try to insert a row with open_date > close_date